# i am passing none value

Tags: django, search

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from shop.models import Product


def search(request):
    products=None
    query=None

    if 'q' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET.get('q')

        products = Product.objects.all().filter(Q(name__contains=query) | Q(description__contains=query))

    return render(request,'search.html',{'query':query,'products':products})
```

**this is my code i always get a none value for products and query**

Comment: What query suppose to be in your expectations? You never update it so it should be none. (query1 is a different variable) Since query is None, you are searching for name__container None, description__contains None criteria which is None with your data I guess.

Comment: actually query and query1 are same. my mistake while typing the code

Comment: did you check if your `request.GET.get('q')` actually return anything? if you got a value then next step is to check in your database. also don't use None, django have api to get empty queryset it's [none()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#none)

Comment: Can you add the request details printed on the very first line of your view? One possible mistake that I consider is URL doesn't contain the `?q=abcd...` part or you can access the q parameter from the request.body attribute instead of request.GET. You can print these and see if q presents or not.

Comment: Actually request.GET('q') return None